# Technical term for the way [n] is working in line 3 (array access)

Tags: javascript, terminology

I understand how this works as I hope i've made clear in the comments, but there is a technicality I'm looking for information about, which is: In line 3 the variable [n] is passed into line 3 in a square brackets format, what is the correct term for passing [n] in square brackets, like say bracket notation? or is that wrong, is the n in square brackets computed first and then computed values passed to the rest of the expression on line 3?

```
while (total < 10) // Line 1: while total is less than 10

{ n++; // Line 2: increment the variable n by 1 each time the loop executes
total += values[n]; // Line 3: Adds the value of an expression to the value 
//of a variable and assigns the result to the variable.
}
```

Comment: `n` is an array index and `values` is an array. So `values` consists of many elements, and [n]` refers to the `n`-th one. Do a Google search on "arrays in JavaScript". Arrays are a common data structure in most computer languages, and the indexing syntax is fairly common as well.

Comment: Read about [JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Access by index / Get by index, would be the proper term ... assuming `values` is an array. Maybe even **random access** by index, because you can get any index (in a random order).
A linked list could not be accessed this way with the same performance.

For object you would say access or get by key.
And for objects if you do `myObject.theKey` then this is call **dot notation**.

Comment: Thanks Christophe, that's really helpful.

Comment: I wonder who actually downvoted my accepted answer ... please comment here or propose an edit instead of downvoting

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
total += values[n];
```

This line means that you have an array called "values" and at each iteration you increment the value of total with the value of the array for index "n" until the total is greater than or equal to 10

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript (ecmascript actually) you can access properties with two **semantics** : dot notation `MemberExpression . IdentifierName` and  bracket notation `MemberExpression[ Expression ]` (which you use in your snippet).

In the first case, `IdentifierName`needs to be a valid Js identifier (no hyphens or cannot start with a number for instance) whereas in the second one it only needs to be a valid **expression**.

This makes the last part of your question easy : what is in the brackets is an expression that needs to be evaluated before the property can be accessed. You should take a look at the specs and / or MDN on the subject for more details.

You can access properties on every values in JS with this syntax, and your program will be syntactically valid, it could result in runtime errors though if you try to access fields on `undefined` or `null`for instance or if some getter throws.